# PTIJ: May a Jew visit an optometrist or opthamologist?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Both ophthamalogists and optometrists are looking at your eyes, and when you visit them, you are encouraging them to do it.

Is there a problem of *mar'it ayin* if they give you a check up? Would there be any difference or leniency if either you or the doctor wears glasses or lenses? Do sunglasses add any protection b/c they can't see your eyes, directly? What about bi-focals - would they be committing two instances of *mar'it ayin*?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Unrelated: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27484

Comment: @msh210 What???

Comment: What was unclear?

Comment: @msh210 "unclear.." - very cute pun - I'm asking an "eye" joke. I don't understand why you linked that question. It is unrelated. Is that part of the Purim humor?

Comment: @msh210 hilarious. On a totally unrelated and non-Purim note I remember the Pardes Yosef having a discussion of whether a Cohen see negaim through glasses, or if he must remove them first.

Comment: @רבות מחשתוב. What about Kriat hatorah through eyeglasses? Or looking at the moon before Kiddush levanah? I think I’ve seen both of these discussed, but can’t track them down now...

Comment: @JoelK Kiddush Levana was also discussed there.  They focused specifically on those because they require a technical "Reiyah", I think.

Answer (score 2):

[Vayikra 13:55](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%A0%D7%94) states that it is an Issur of Sereifah to visit such an eye doctor:

וראה ... את עינו ... באש תשרפנו

It is unclear if the ophthamalogists and optometrists are Chayav Sereifah, or maybe the person who goes to them.

Comment: It seems to mean that he should burn *the eye*. Does this not mean that a doctor is commanded to cauterize a patient’s eye if needed to save his life?

Answer (score 1):

You ask a very good question. How many of us have stopped to think that we may be committing a transgression when we go to see an eye doctor? However, it is still permitted, for the reason I have outlined below.

It is well known that the source for מארית עין is in [Berachos 34b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.34b.21?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where it clearly states,

> הבא עין לא ראתה - One who brings an eye, do not look at it.

Looking at eyes is clearly not acceptable. However, it seems like viewing eyes may be מותר, from the גמרא in [Sanhedrin 75a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.75a.2?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אמר רב יהודה אמר רב מעשה באדם אחד שנתן עיניו באשה אחת והעלה לבו טינא ובאו ושאלו לרופאים - Rav Yehuda says in the name of Rav: There was a case with a certain man who gave away his eyes to a certain lady, and his heart filled with jealousy (i.e. he regretted giving his eyes away), and they came and lent [the eyes] to the doctors. (presumably to study them.)

This גמרא is difficult, because during the time that the eyes were in the custody of the doctors, they must have been looking at them! How does this fit with the גמרא that says it is אסור to view eyes?

The answer is found in the [Yerushalmi Avoda Zarah 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Avodah_Zarah.9b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi):

> רופא אומן מותר - [for a] skilled doctor it is permitted (to view eyes).

The whole issue of מארית עין is that a person viewing the eyes may become tempted touch them because of their beauty ([Shabbos 74a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.74a.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi) - עין יפה - an eye is beautiful), and thereby damage them. Therefore, חזל instituted the תקנה that people should avoid looking at eyes. But for a skilled doctor, who is both able to look at eyes without ending up touching them, and can touch eyes without damaging them, חזל was lenient, at least specifically for healing purposes.

This is the reason for why the doctors mentioned in Sanhedrin were able to have the eyes in their custody. They did not only intend to study the eyes, but also to determine if it was possible to return them to the man who had donated them.

So in your case, it is indeed מותר for an optometrist to view your eyes; however for a regular person it will be אסור.